# Get RGB value (from GetPreviewBufferArgb) using AudioVideoCaptureDevice WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, buffer, windows-phone

I want to use AudioVideoCaptureDevice in Windows Phone 8 to calculate RGB value from a Video. I want to use AudioVideoCaptureDevice because it can set certain property others cannot like VideoTorch. Now, I can capture a video with AudioVideoCaptureDevice with Videotorch On. But Can I analyze the video to get RGB value from frame to frame (microsecond calcualtion)?

I do not think it is possible. I do not know actually.

But I think there is an another way is getting RGB value from previewbuffer (using live feed). I know how to use it with capturedevice or photocamera. I also could get get the RGB value using PhotoCamera.But, Can I get the RGB value from PreviewBuffer using 
AudioVideoCaptureDevice? How Can I use this function ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.audiovideocapturedevice.getpreviewbufferargb%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Please I Really need help. Any opinion will be a big help for me. Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

Did it, now got the RGB value for ten seconds. Followed:

1. Set the camera using audiovideocapturedevice.
2. VideoTorchmode on for camera.
3. Get the camera pixels from preview.
4. Get every pixels in a array.
5. Read out the array and use the getpreviewbufferargb to get the RGB value of every frame.
6. Count for the frame and make avg from total/count.
7. make the loop for ten seconds.